# Define fonts in Beamer

Tags: latex, presentation, beamer

I want to define distinct fonts for text and math. I used this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\renewcommand {\rmdefault }{ibh} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe Print}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmbr}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Some text, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but it has a inverse result:[image: click here]

How can i correct it?

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark the answer below as accepted, if it solves! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may need the package `lmodern` too:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe Print}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Some text, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code, compiled with LuaLaTeX, gives:

[image: output frame]

Also, check the option `no-math` of package `fontspec`.